# What is a good way to manage multiple characters?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

On Skyrim, it seems very difficult to manage multiple characters. Their quicksaves overwrite each other and you have to trace back the date of when you last did a "full save" to load a different character.

Outside of swapping the save files, is there a better way to manage multiple characters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [Skyrim Character Manager](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=2119).

It modifies your ini file upon startup and lets you choose between characters.

Comment: I am seeing some mixed reviews about it.  Support seems to have stopped a few months after this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [Profile Manager](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/10345/) it works the same way as the Skyrim Character manager, but has more features and works on more games.

Answer (score 2):

[Wrye Bash](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/1840) have a profile feature, that not only manage the saves, but also the mods activated with them.

To use it, got to the save tab, right click on a column header, then profile->manage profile. This allows you to create new profiles. You can then move or copy saves to a profile, and it will remember the activated mods when switching.

Answer (score 2):

**Skyrim Special Edition** now allows you to load specific characters' save files.

Answer (score 0):

I personally manage my character save files by saving with the console. You can name the saves whatever you like using this method, and I just continually overwrite the same save state. For example, lets say I have a Khajiit melee assassin, I would use the console to save like so:

`save stabbytabby`

If I want to reload from that save:

`load stabbytabby`

From the home menu of the game, these show up like normal save entries, but with the custom names you give them, rather than dates.